# Filter from duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where columns name as

- ViewAllLogId *primary key*
- orderNumber
- UserLocation
- tractor
- status

In this table there can be multiple same status and tractor exists for a ordernumber and userlocation. I want filter distinct all row GROUP BY UserLocation, orderNumber where tractor name is not empty.

Here is my query ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.ViewAllLog VAL 
WHERE ViewAllLogId IN
(
  SELECT MAX(ViewAllLogId) as ViewAllLogId 
  FROM dbo.ViewAllLog VAL 
  WHERE VAL.UserLocation IN ('hci') 
  and VAL.status IN ('DRPL','DRPE')
  --AND ISNULL(VAL.tractor,'') <> '' 
  GROUP BY VAL.UserLocation, VAL.orderNumber 
)
```

Comment: I don't understand `i want filter distinct all row GROUP BY ...`. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you show sample data and expected result, please?

Comment: What is the question and what's wrong with the query? People shouldn't have to *guess*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too much clear from your description but i think you need tractor null checking and distinct

```
SELECT distinct VAL.* 
FROM dbo.ViewAllLog VAL 
WHERE ViewAllLogId IN
(
  SELECT MAX(ViewAllLogId) as ViewAllLogId 
  FROM dbo.ViewAllLog VAL 
  WHERE VAL.UserLocation IN ('hci') 
  and VAL.status IN ('DRPL','DRPE')
  AND VAL.tractor is not null 
  GROUP BY VAL.UserLocation, VAL.orderNumber 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
With cte as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by orderNumber,UserLocation,tractor,[status] 
order by orderNumber,UserLocation,tractor,[status]) rn 
from ViewAllLog
)
select orderNumber,UserLocation,count(*) as Order_Count 
from cte 
where rn=1 and tractor!='' and tractor is not null 
group by orderNumber,UserLocation
```

SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(

    ViewAllLogId INT  primary key,
    orderNumber VARCHAR(50),
    UserLocation VARCHAR(50),
    tractor VARCHAR(50),
    status VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT INTO 
Test(ViewAllLogId,orderNumber, UserLocation, tractor, status) 
VALUES(1, '0001','hci', 'Trac1', 'DRPL')
VALUES(2, '0001','hci', 'Trac1', 'DRPL')
VALUES(3, '0001','hci', 'Trac1', 'DRPE')
VALUES(4, '0002', 'bci', 'Trac2', 'DRPL')
VALUES(5, '0001', 'hci', 'Trac1', 'DRPE')
VALUES(6, '0001','hci', null, 'DRPL')
VALUES(7,    '0003',' aci', 'Trac3', 'DRPE')

With ITL AS
(
    SELECT      
            ViewAllLogId,
            orderNumber,
            UserLocation,
            tractor,
            status
    FROM Test
    WHERE 
        Test.UserLocation IN ('hci') 
    AND Test.status IN ('DRPL','DRPE')
    AND Test.tractor is not null 

   )
   SELECT DISTINCT Status, OrderNumber, UserLocation, Tractor
   FROM ITL 


   DROP TABLE Test
```

Answer (score 0):

where cnt > 1 that is duplicate row

```
SELECT val.* 
FROM (
      SELECT UserLocation, orderNumber, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM dbo.ViewAllLog 
      WHERE UserLocation IN ('hci') 
      and status IN ('DRPL','DRPE')
      --AND ISNULL(VAL.tractor,'') <> '' 
      GROUP BY UserLocation, orderNumber 
) AS val
WHERE val.cnt > 1
```